# color selector in aptana

Tags: colors, aptana

Is there any color selector in Aptana? I mean, like the one that Dreamweaver displays when you are trying to choose an hexadecimal color, a small box of pre-defined colours. Thank you!

Comment: Bumping this as I think it would be a handy tool to have.

Answer (score 5):

If you are editing a .css file, you can find a color picker at `Commands->CSS->Insert color`

Answer (score 4):

There is no option for Aptana by default. Someone is developing one, according a blog post in aptanastudio (http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/826-color-picker-css-editor) , but you can use an online tool like Chroma (http://lucumalabs.com/chroma/) instead

Comment: another suggestion if you don't know the hex code...[http://www.colorpicker.com/](http://www.colorpicker.com/)